# Is there a library function that merges objects while concatenating any arrays it finds?

Tags: javascript

I'm dealing with an API that returns a complex object in several different update messages. I've discovered that JQuery's extend(true, objA, objB) function does a great job for merging together the updates, with one exception: when a property is an array, it replaces the array instead of concatenating.

So I have objects like this:

```
{thing:{stuff:{whatsit:{foo:[1,2,3]}}}}}
{thing:{stuff:{whatsit:{foo:[3,4,5,6]}}}}}
```

Is there an existing NPM package or other library that will give this result when merging objects:

```
{thing:{stuff:{whatsit:{foo:[1,2,3,3,4,5,6]}}}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lodash is a good option. you can use _.mergeWith function for your case.
example from lodash api guide

```js
function customizer(objValue, srcValue) {
  if (_.isArray(objValue)) {
    return objValue.concat(srcValue);
  }
}
 
var object = { 'a': [1], 'b': [2] };
var other = { 'a': [3], 'b': [4] };
 
_.mergeWith(object, other, customizer);
// => { 'a': [1, 3], 'b': [2, 4] }
```

Comment: Ah, I thought _.extend was lodash's only option.  This is perfect, especially since I already have lodash in the project!